# Как из MySQL вытащить только единичные результаты?

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице есть поле, и в этом поле очень много разных значений и они могут повторяться, мне нужно вытащить результаты, но если они повторяются, то вывести только один раз. Для этого даже есть опредленный синтаксис для Select. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почитайте про Нормальные Формы. Это не очень хорошо так хранить данные.

Comment: Описание вогнало в ступор о_О

Comment: слово distinct?

Comment: @Construct данные хранить можно в том случае если - допустим через запятую указаны те же метки и LIKE в запросе)

Comment: @Palvervan, ну да, но, судя по описанию, у ТС там храниться много данных.

Comment: Простит за мое корявое описание) по другому не получилось.
Да спасибо дестинкт сработал.
А как вывести еще число совпадений? без доп запросов?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду кол-во полученых записей, то функция **mysql_num_rows()**

Comment: @blud. `select id, count(*) from tab group by id`. Но вот как поступать с остальными полями таблицы, зависит от того, что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table
```